# Creating a CRUD model in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: api, extjs, local-storage, sencha-touch-2, crud

I have started using sencha touch 2 recently. I am working on a CRUD model and I have done the entire scripting. The form is working great but it only works for 'local storage'. The code is  as follows

```
 App.models.User = Ext.regModel('User', {
 fields: [
    {
        name: 'active',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'resource_type',
        type: 'string'
    } ],

validations: [
    {
        type: 'presence',
        name: 'name'
    } ],proxy: {
    type: 'localstorage',
    id: 'sencha-users'}});
```

But I want to create/read/update/delete the data using a certain api and therefore will have to use rest/ajax proxy. However, when I use the ajax proxy the changes are not being reflected in the url of the api.
If anybody is willing to help, I can share more details.
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "the changes are not being reflected in the url of the api"?

Comment: The api is defined on this url-
http://svc2-staging.mypsn.com/v1/cams/resources

So what I basically want is that when I enter the data in the form, it should be updated there but at present, I am able to fill the form but the data is only stored in localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is when ... say your Submit button is pressed, then triggered a POST request to your API:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: API_URL,
        params: {your_params_here},

        success: function(result) {
          // successfully saved on the server
        },

        failure: function(){
          // failed
        }   
    });
```

This means that your back-end server must have an API used to save data, for example:

> yourdomain?api=save_data&param1=abc&param2=xyz